# Migrate all data from excell to sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

l m fresh user of `python`.l m working on `SQL`.l would like to migrate data from excel file to `SQL`.
Here is my code:

```
import xlrd
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect("student.db")
crs=conn.cursor()

file_path="student.xlsx"

file=xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
sheet=file.sheet_by_index(0)
data=[[sheet.cell_value(r,c)for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
for i in range(sheet.ncols):
    colm=data[0][i]
    crs.execute(("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student([%s] VARCHAR(100))")%colm)
```

firstly, l tried to create tables by using column in excel file but l could not do it. After that , l would like to insert each row in columns. probably, l m doing wrong somewhere but l could not figure out.

Comment: Create the table before you insert data. What's the error message you get with this code?

Comment: excel file has own columns and l would like to use them as tables.so l need to create them first, After that ,insert all data?

Comment: Think of a table as an excel sheet. It can be many columns. Having one table per column does not sound like a good design

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just add the whole table into your sqlite database?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

file = pd.DataFrame("student.xlsx") #assuming your import this as a PD dataframe? You may want to include the path of the file if it is not in your working directory
'yourtablename'.to_sql("file", conn, if_exists="replace")

conn.commit()
```

'yourtablename' should be replaced by whatever name you want to give the table in your database. You can then use the below code to verify that you table is in the database

```
con = sqlite3.connect('student.db')
cur = con.cursor() 
cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;")
cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: l have tried the code above but l run into a problem " DataFrame constructor not properly called python".Pandas DataFrame is not able to get data from excel. after l solved the problem. the code above was wrong and l fixed it and l got a result but it was not what l want

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlrd
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect("student.db")
crs = conn.cursor()

file_path = "C:/Users/LANDGIS10/PycharmProjects/sqlite/student.xlsx"

file=xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
sheet = file.sheet_by_index(0)
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_sql("student1",conn,if_exists="replace")
conn.commit()
crs.fetchall()
```

However ,it is not what l want as Columns are in excel migrating in `sqlite` as row instead of `table head`.here is the result.

```
"0" "ID"    "NO"    "NAME"  "SURNAME"
"1" "1.0"   "1234.0"    "Ali"   "ARSA"
"2" "2.0"   "23234.0"   "Mehmet"    "KOT"
"3" "3.0"   "234412.0"  "Adem"  "SAR"
```

l want `"ID"    "NO"    "NAME"  "SURNAME"`this part as table head.